# bold part of text string code behind

Tags: c#, xaml

We built an application in XAML. Now I need to format the text strings.
Is it possible to bold only part of the text string. We are replacing an element's text in a XAML textblock with a text string. What would be the easiest way to make parts of the text string bold? Would I add a label? Something else in the XAML or in the C#?

Here is an example of our XAML and our code behind:

XAML

`<TextBlock x:Name="PrimaryNameText" Text="Primary Member Name:"></TextBlock>`

C# String

`PrimaryNameText.Text = "Primary Member Name: " + reAccount.MyPerson.Prefix + " " + reAccount.MyPerson.FirstName + " " + reAccount.MyPerson.LastName;`

In the example above, we more or less want to bold the part of the string "Primary Member Name: "

I know you can do a "\n" for a page break, is there a way we can do something for bolding text in the string?

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating UI elements in code in XAML-based technologies. Now you'll have to do a bunch of code in order to achieve this, versus the simplicity of a DataBinding you could have if you did the things the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a span inside your TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock> 
    <Span x:Name="PrimaryNameBold" FontWeight="Bold"></Span> 
    <Span x:Name="PrimaryNameNormal"></Span> 
</TextBlock>
```

And in your code:

```
PrimaryNameBold.Text = "Primary Member Name: ";
PrimaryNameNormal.Text = reAccount.MyPerson.Prefix + " " + reAccount.MyPerson.FirstName + " " + reAccount.MyPerson.LastName;
```

Not an awesome solution, but this should work.

Comment: I like your solution.  Seems very viable.  I know our code is not beautiful but I think it will work

Comment: @Carlos I haven't tested this for any potential weirdness, but it should work. So let me know if it does.

Comment: That worked quite nicely. All except had to take the quotes from around the PrimaryNameNormal.Text. The whole thing does not need the quotes around it. Other than that. That worked. Thanks

Comment: @Carlos Excellent. If you feel this resolved your question, would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: I actually need to edit it.  But I will accept yours as the answer with the edit.

Comment: @Carlos Fixed it. Totally missed that.